# 2002 Ford Taurus shakes and dies at idle and has a gas smell at high speed

Tags: fuel-system, idle, shaking, taurus

My mother has a 2002 Taurus that keeps giving her problems.  The latest issue is it shakes very badly and dies at idle and at very slow speeds when breaking.  If she gets it going up to highway speeds a gas odor is detected inside the car.  She had the codes ran which show:
Lead codes Running lean
O2 Sensor code
DPE Sensor code
Please help if you can.

Comment: Smell of gas is dangerous, take it to a qualified repair shop to find the leak, this is very dangerous, stop driving it!

Answer (score 0):

May or may not be a problem..But check all Vacuum hoses on eng especially on computer control EGR control Valve  A big leak or blown hose will cause the DPE code , Plus if hose blown (melted) will cause stalling, rough idle and smell through the air intake duct.. If you have a GOOD mechanic take it to them. Don't take it to a jerk. Was a NAISE certified mech for over 30 years.. You would be surprised how FEW good mechanics are out there. GOOD LUCK..